# Combine a date and a factor to make a POSIXct date time and strip into columns

Tags: r

I have a POSIXct object and I want to combine only the date from that object with the time that is stored in a factor object. here is the code:

```
 originalDate<- as.POSIXct("2014-10-27 13:39:01.885")

 time<- factor("13:30:00.994")
 class(time)
 time

 #I'd like to combine the date from "originalDate" and the time from "time" 
  #so is of the type POSIXct and is --> 2014-10-27 13:30:00.994
```

Also once I have that new POSIXct object I need to strip the hour, minute, second and millisecond into columns.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
temp <- paste(as.Date(doriginalDate), time)
temp
## [1] "2014-10-27 13:30:00.994"
as.numeric(strsplit(format(as.POSIXct(temp), "%H:%M:%OS3"), ":|\\.")[[1]])
## [1]  13  30   0 993
```

Comment: Awesome. Do you konw how to extract the hour, minute, second and millisecond from that output?

Comment: Yes, but what do you want to do with them? I.e., what is your new desired output?

Comment: desired output is hour = 13 minute = 30 second = 0 and millisecond = 994  in numeric type